# In R how to calculate if Date is earlier then date X?

Tags: r, if-statement, as.date

I got a DF with a date column in it. I want to check if the date in the column is after or before 1st of January 2020. Create a new column and if the previous columns date is before then insert 1st of January 2020 if not then insert previous columns date.

Date is in format YYYY-MM-DD

```
 
Beginning    End
2020-12-31  2021-01-12
2018-01-02  2020-03-10
2019-04-12  2020-12-04
2020-10-15  2021-03-27
```

I want:

```
 
Beginning      End        Beginning_2
2020-12-31  2021-01-12     2020-12-31
2018-01-02  2020-03-10     2020-01-01 
2019-04-12  2020-12-04     2020-01-01 
2020-10-15  2021-03-27     2020-10-15
```

The code i wrote is:
DF$Beginning_2 <- ifelse("2020-01-01" > DF$Beginning,"2020-01-01", DF$Beginning)

I'm getting this

```
 
Beginning      End        Beginning_2
2020-12-31  2021-01-12     18554 
2018-01-02  2020-03-10     2020-01-01 
2019-04-12  2020-12-04     2020-01-01  
2020-10-15  2021-03-27     18453
```

My code works half way. It turns the format in to char. I need it to stay as date. I tried butting as date all over the code but nothing much changed. The biggest change was that greater then 2020-01-01 dates were NA instead of "18554".

How to fix my code?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pmax`:

```
DF$Beginning_2 <- pmax(DF$Beginning, as.Date("2020-01-01"))
#DF$Beginning_2 <- pmax(DF$Beginning, "2020-01-01") #Works also

DF
#   Beginning        End Beginning_2
#1 2020-12-31 2021-01-12  2020-12-31
#2 2018-01-02 2020-03-10  2020-01-01
#3 2019-04-12 2020-12-04  2020-01-01
#4 2020-10-15 2021-03-27  2020-10-15

str(DF)
#'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Beginning  : Date, format: "2020-12-31" "2018-01-02" ...
# $ End        : Date, format: "2021-01-12" "2020-03-10" ...
# $ Beginning_2: Date, format: "2020-12-31" "2020-01-01" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R `ifelse` would return dates as numbers you will need to convert them back to dates.

```
DF$Beginning_2 <- as.Date(ifelse(DF$Beginning > as.Date("2020-01-01"), 
                  DF$Beginning, as.Date("2020-01-01")), origin = '1970-01-01')
```

You may use `dplyr::if_else` which will maintain the class of the date columns.

```
DF$Beginning_2 <- dplyr::if_else(DF$Beginning > as.Date("2020-01-01"), 
                         DF$Beginning, as.Date("2020-01-01"))

DF

#   Beginning        End Beginning_2
#1 2020-12-31 2021-01-12  2020-12-31
#2 2018-01-02 2020-03-10  2020-01-01
#3 2019-04-12 2020-12-04  2020-01-01
#4 2020-10-15 2021-03-27  2020-10-15
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about dplyr if_else. It's good to know that it does not change the class.